# Div won't fill the empty space

Tags: html, css

I believe that this is the default behavior of CSS but I'm not sure why and it would be great if someone can explain it.

Content has 3 div tags (A,B,C). A and B are floating taking the 100% of width(60%+40%) but their height is different. A is 300px, B is 400px in height. C has width of 40% and it is also floating to the left.

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.column-a {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}

.column-b {
  width: 40%;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.sub-columns {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="column-a">A</div>
    <div class="column-b">B</div>
    <div class="sub-columns">C</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My idea was that C is placed right beneath the A because there is room, bit it seems that browser won't place it there because B div is higher than A and C appears under the B div. Image:

[image]

Why is this happening, shouldn't be C placed underneath A?

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: @Amit Why is this happening, shouldn't be C placed underneath A?

Comment: No. Floats don't "optimize" space like that - but you already know that as you said yourself. not sure what's the question here.

Comment: This is just how it works in CSS. I think the simplest workaround for you would be wrapping A and C in separate div and this new div should be 60% wide.

Comment: @Amit As I wrote can someone explain "why is this happening", that was the question.

Comment: Well in this simple case you can simply achieve what you want by floating `B` to the _right_ instead of left ...

Comment: This work this way because C is next to B and all the place on the left side of B is already taken by B. And C have no place on the right side of B so it gets a new "row". Something like that :p Its confusing but thats how I understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to *why* this is happening - it's because the behaviour of floated elements is *specified* this way.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats has a lists titled "Here are the precise rules that govern the behavior of floats", and the second item on that list is:

> 2. If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.

Since there is no space for C next to B, the "the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box" part of the requirement can not be fulfilled - so "its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box" becomes applicable.

---

You got to keep in mind that `float` is basically a property from the "stone ages" of CSS. It was never even *intended* for creating "column layouts", but simply to have text float around an image, simple stuff like that. Of course we used it for columns for a long time - but that's because we had nothing else really suitable to do the job, and rather not because it was the proper tool for this to begin with. But browsers at the time were much less sophisticated, and that is probably the main reason it was specified *this* way - relatively easy to implement (and nevertheless Internet Explorer managed to mess up floating/clearing for a *long* time.) Had someone thrown a flexbox or grid specification at browser developers at that time, they'd probably gone, *you gotta be kidding us, this kind of complexity is unmanageable with the resources and computing power we have available here ... if that's what you demand, we're not gonna bother to start implementing this "CSS" thing in the first place, you crazy kids* ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherent behavior of floats, the space is occupied by the highest element.

If you want to achieve this layout without resorting to JS and masonry plugins, try flexbox.

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column-a {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  order: 1;
}

.column-b {
  width: 40%;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  order: 3;
}

.sub-columns {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="column-a">A</div>
  <div class="column-b">B</div>
  <div class="sub-columns">C</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mp32qjf2/1/